# Groovy script to find all the Jobs with name "Team CT" and disable them

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson

Groovy script to find all the Jobs with name "Team CT" from all Jenkins jobs and disable them at once without any impact any other Jenkins Jobs.

(I have 1000+jobs and "Team CT" named jobs will be somewhere inside). Could someone help me to write a script to achieve this requirement ??

Answer (score 1):

Open Jenkins script console: http://yourJenkins/script and use the following:

```
def jobTypes = [hudson.model.FreeStyleProject.class] // add more types as needed
def filterClosure = { item -> item.getDisplayName().contains("Team CT") }
def disableClosure = { item -> item.disable() }

jobTypes.each{ className ->
    jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(className).findAll(filterClosure).each(disableClosure)}
```

The script gets all items FreeStyleProject items, filter only those who has "Team CT" in their name and disable them.